# How to visualize a list of lists of lists of ... in R?

Tags: r

I have a very deep list of lists in R. Now I want to print this list to the standard output to get a better overview of the elements. It should look like the way the StatET plugin for eclipse shows a list. 
Example list:

```
l6 = list()
l6[["h"]] = "one entry"
l6[["g"]] = "nice"
l5 = list()
l5[["e"]] = l6
l4 = list()
l4[["f"]] = "test"
l4[["d"]] = l5
l3 = list()
l3[["c"]] = l4
l2 = list()
l2[["b"]] = l3
l1 = list()
l1[["a"]] = l2
```

This should print like:

```
List of 1
 $ a:List of 1
  ..$ b:List of 1
  .. ..$ c:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ f: chr "test"
  .. .. ..$ d:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ e:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ h: chr "one entry"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ g: chr "nice"
```

I know this is possible with recursion and the deepness.
But is there a way to do this with the help of `rapply` or something like that?

Thanx in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you could get what you want by giving

```
str(l1)
```

Comment: Great! It's as simple as that. Thank you!